# How do I get the consecutive elements between two identical elements in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, between

For example I have a list `l = ['.','b','w','w','w','b','.','.']`, how would I traverse this list and return the indices of the three w's that are between the b's.

I need to be able to handle cases such as `l = ['.','b','w','w','w','w','.','.']`, where there is no second 'b', in this case nothing would be returned. Other cases that could be encountered are `l = ['.','b','w','w','.','.','b','.']`, in this case nothing would be returned either. I need to be able to get the consecutive w's between the b's. What I have tried so far is this:

```
l = ['.','b','w','w','.','.','.','.']
q = []
loop = False
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == 'b' and l[i+1] == 'w':
        loop = True
    elif l[i] == 'w' and l[i+1] == 'w' and l[i+2] == '.':
        pass
    elif l[i] == 'w' and l[i-1] == 'b' and l[i+1] == 'w' and loop == True:
        q.append(i)
    elif l[i-1] == 'w' and l[i] == 'w' and l[i+1] == 'w' and loop == True:               q.append(i)
    elif l[i] == 'w' and l[i+1] == 'b' and loop == True:
        q.append(i)
        loop = False
        break

print(q)
```

But this does not handle all cases and sometimes returns errors. How could I go about doing this **without numpy**?

Comment: a bit of a tangent, but why the try except pass?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yea that's unnecessary I'm not sure why I put in in there

Comment: Is it always b and w?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Paulin Yes but it switches between b and w, as in either consecuive b's between two w's, or like in the post consecutive w's between two b's

Comment: @AltaafAckbar is it always only 3 different symbols (`.`, `b`, `w`) ?

Comment: @Ralf, yes it is only those three symbols  (. , b, w)

Comment: can you provide more samples for your input?

Comment: What about some like `bwwwbwwwb` or `bwwwwb`

Comment: @AltaafAckbar check my answer, it should be a good start :)

Comment: @MitchelPaulin This is for a project of the Reversi game, so there would not be cases with two consecutive "sets". The input would never be something like `bwwbwwb`, it would always be only one set or no set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ind = [i for i, e in enumerate(l) if e == 'b']
q = []

if len(ind) == 2:
    w = l[ind[0]+1: ind[1]]
    if set(w) == {'w'}:
        for i in range(ind[0]+1, ind[1]):        
            q.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re
l = ['.','b','w','w','b','.','.','.']
s = ''.join(l)

# print(re.findall('[b]([w]+)[b]',s))
# print(re.findall('[w]([b]+)[w]',s))

if(re.findall('[b]([w]+)[b]',s)):
    witer =re.finditer('w',s)
    wpos = []
    for i in witer:
        wpos.append(i.start())
    print('reverse', wpos)


if(re.findall('[w]([b]+)[w]',s)):
    biter =re.finditer('b',s)
    bpos = []
    for i in biter:
        bpos.append(i.start())
    print('reverse', bpos)
```

Comment: @YonkangZhao, Sorry I am not familiar with the re library, so I am not sure where to go from here?

Comment: re library is basically for regular expression, it is a very powerful tool for string manipulation and data extraction. regex should suit your case is very well. let me know what it is that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Also I would like to get the indices of the consecutive w's, not just how many w's, how could I do this?

Comment: That works great, but there is one last case it doesn't catch though. The third example case in my post is `['.','b','w','w','.','.','b','.']`, in this case nothing would be returned. Thanks for all the help so far btw.

Comment: re.findall('[b]([w]+)[b]',s) doesn't return anything, you mean you want to also not return indicies of w's?

Comment: yes exactly, in that third case I would want no indices

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the code to be exactly, but at this point it is really simple enough to figure it out yourself. just apply some if statements. I have edited again to give you some idea on what to do.

Comment: Alright thank you, yea I think I can figure it out from here :)